# run the join when the group by value has changed

Tags: sql

Hi I am writing the following query and the results are not what I need

**Section 1**

```
     select

          case_PrimaryCompanyId as companyid,
          CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),ca.case_createddate, 111) AS Date,
          'Moving Balance' as InvoiceType,
          sum( mb.Amount) as Amount
from  cases as ca
```

**Section 2**

```
left join (
select
    case_PrimaryCompanyId as companyid,
    case_createdDate,
    case_TotalExVat as Amount
from cases  ) mb

on ca. case_primaryCompanyId = mb.companyid  
     and ca.case_createdDate >= mb.case_CreatedDate

where
    ca.case_primaryCompanyId = companyid 

group by
     case_primaryCompanyId,
     CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),ca.case_createddate, 111)
```

Ok so the above will get a  list of  data as below and group it by month and year and  aggregate the amount since the  beginning of time.

```
Date            Actual Amount                
20/10/2009      1766.52
07/11/2009      2778.02
14/01/2010     -2700.00
28/02/2010       -78.02

27/05/2010      2489.40
27/05/2010      2491.20
30/05/2010      2494.80
```

Everything works perfectly , calculating the cummlative value for each month.

until i get to may 2010 and then the moving balance is calculated for each record of may instead of once for may (instead of only once when the group value changes)

```
Moving Balance Result

Date         Displays            Should be
2009/10       1766.52             1766.52
2009/11       2788.02             2788.02
2010/01         78.02               78.02
2010/02          0.00                0.00

2010/05      22426.20             7475.50
```

Have Tried 
sum(distinct mb.Amount) but that doesnt work

Any ideas would be  really appreciated
Thanks
Rachael

Comment: It looks like you're using SQL Server. Which version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right after much frustration and a few weeks of hair pulling ,

i finally got this problem sorted,

I took out the join and just used a select statement

```
(
SELECT 
       case_PrimaryCompanyId as companyid,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),case_createddate, 111) AS Date,
       case_invoicetype as InvoiceType,
       Sum(case_totalexvat) as Amount
FROM   cases AS ca
WHERE  
datediff(m,case_createddate,getDate()) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),b.case_createddate, 111) and b.case_primarycompanyid = a.case_primarycompanyid
)PrevSum 
from  cases a
where 

  CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),a.case_createddate, 111)  > Convert(VARCHAR(7), DATEADD(m, -13, current_timestamp), 111)
group by a.case_primarycompanyid, CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),a.case_createddate, 111)

) 
order by Date, InvoiceType
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put the query that produces your result set into the `with` clause

```
;with results as 
(
     select 
          convert(varchar(4),YEAR(date)) + right('00'+convert(varchar(2),MONTH(date)),2) m, 
          sum(amount) a 
     from 
          (-- your results here ) data 
     group by YEAR(date), MONTH(date)
)
select 
     *,
     (select SUM(a) from results r1 where r1.m<=results.m)
from results
order by m
```

Comment: Thanks podiluska, Going to look into this , it seems fairly straight forward, never heard of the with clause, Will let you know if it works. Thanks

Comment: Hi Podiluska  I tried that but i am getting the same results , do i need to make the group by result distinct or something ?

Comment: A `group by` result will always be `distinct`, by definition.

Comment: then i am very confused because if there are three records for the month, the sum is calculated 3 times. I dont know why this is happening, as i would have assumed that group by makes everything distinct but my results are still incorrect.

Comment: @Rachsherry I've updated the answer so that it is self contained. You should be able to run that. Where does your code differ?

Comment: Hi Podiluska, What do i put in for (-- your results here) data?

Comment: @Rachsherry Whatever query produces the first set of results, inside the brackets